# Where does one get pretty screensavers for Xubuntu (xfce, xscreensaver)?

Tags: screensaver, xubuntu

I browsed through the default set of screensavers and the most are ugly, a couple are decent and the only quality ones are Flurry, GLSlideshow, MetaBalls are PopSquares. Where does one find more nice screensavers for Xubuntu? APT repository or xfce-look.org doesn't seem to have it. Or would you recommend running gnome-screensaver instead of xscreensaver? What options are there so that my screen doesn't display rough (not antialiased) visualizations of mathematic obsessions?

Answer (score 10):

Have you added the following packages using Synaptic Package Manager?

`xscreensaver-data`, `xscreensaver-data-extra`, `xscreensaver-gl`,`xscreensaver-gl-extra`, `rss-glx`

These are the screensaver files themselves. For the rss-glx screensavers, please read the documentation in `/usr/share/doc/rss-glx` to properly install them into xscreensaver.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you give [electricsheep](http://electricsheep.org/) a try. Looks nice, IMO, but be aware that over time it will build up files in the ".electricsheep" folder in your home directory.

```
sudo apt-get install electricsheep
```

Answer (score -1):

Xscreensaver is a dated application and you would not find too many good good looking screensavers for it. I would personally recommend that you use gnome-screensaver. Look here if you have any problems.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/using-gnome-screensaver-in-xfce-and-not-xscreensaver-458516/

Comment: Xubuntu removed gnome-screensaver as default.

Comment: as of Xubuntu 14.04 newly added LightDM is not compatible with xscreensaver and gnome-screensaver is too tightly integrated with GNOME.